# From directories create files changing their ending

Tags: linux

I have several directories with a pattern:

```
$find -name "*.out" 
./trnascanse.out
./darn.out
./blast_rnaz.out
./erpin.out
./rnaspace_cli.out
./yass.out
./atypicalgc.out
./blast.out
./combine.out
./infernal.out
./ecoli.out
./athaliana.out
./yass_carnac.out
./rnammer.out
```

I can get the list into a file `find -name "*.out" > files` because I want to create for each directory a file  ending with `.ref` instead of `.out` : `trnascanse.ref`, `darn.ref`, `blast_rnaz.ref`and so on.

I would say that this is possible with some `grep` and `touch` but I don't know how to do it. Any idea? Or just create each one manually is the only way (as I did with this directories). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
for d in *.out ; do echo touch "${d%.out}.ref" ; done
```

The ${d%.out} expands $d and removes the trailing .out. Read about it in the bash man page.

If the output of above one-liner looks ok, pipe it to `sh` , or remove the `echo` and re-run it.

Comment: The output of the line is of type: `mv rnammer.out rnammer.ref`
Then I get this message: `mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `rnammer.ref' with directory `rnammer.out'` for each one and nothing happened.

Comment: @Llopis Sorry, I read it as you want to rename some directories. Just use touch as I edited now. However that error messages says that you already have file named rnammer.ref

Comment: Well I created manually this files.. Your edit worked fine so I assume the initial code with `mv` insted of `touch`also worked (if I wouldn't  messed it). Thanks

Comment: I am sooo noob that I can't find how to read more about the  `${d%.out}` part of code, could you point me how? I tried `info $` or `d%` and looking to the `touch` manual, but I wasn't able to find it. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned, it's in the bash manual. `man bash` and search for Parameter Expansion

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d  -printf "%f" -exec bash -c "mkdir $(echo '{}' | sed 's/\.out$//').ref" \;
```

Comment: This is the message it says this command: `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.`
It has also created directories of type `darn.out.ref`, without removing the `.out`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. However it was just a warning. Have updated the post

Comment: Thanks but @nos was quicker, sorry